# Sending Push notification using Pushetta in Java results in 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, push-notification, http-status-code-403

I'm referring to the java example from http://api.pushetta.com/pushetta-docs/

I do pass the correct channel and token (API Key), but I'm getting

```
Response Code : 403
Response Message : FORBIDDEN
```

Can you please advise? Thanks.

This is the code I'm using:

```
public class PushNotification {

// settings
public static String channel = "Recognition";
public static String token = "e9897f1ce470f302bdfc8c8167ff489fb0c0fc19";

public static void sendNotification(String message) {

    String url = "http://api.pushetta.com/api/pushes/" + channel + "/";

    try {
        URL obj = new URL(url);

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // set reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Host", "api.pushetta.com");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Chrome");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // API parameters
        String urlParameters = "{ \"body\" : \"" + message + "\", \"message_type\" : \"text/plain\"  }";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        String responseMessage = con.getResponseMessage();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);

        // response information
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        System.out.println("Response Message : " + responseMessage);

        // read response
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // complete html page response if you wanna print it
        String res = response.toString();

        // extract result
        int aux = res.indexOf("success");
        int auxx = res.indexOf(",", aux);
        System.out.println(res.substring(aux, aux + 7) + " : " + res.substring(aux + 15, auxx));

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PushNotification.sendNotification("Recognized");
  }
}
```

Comment: show your code, all of it.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki - added

Comment: FYI - I tried to do a POST to http://api.pushetta.com/api/auth/ with the username/password - it returns 400 Bad Request when executed from Java and 401 Unathorized {"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."} when executed through browser REST client

Comment: Also, FYI - this is fine using the python code

Comment: Are you sure this channel name is correct? It could even matter if it is written in lower or upper letters.

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I've found it, in all examples, the Authorization header takes the form:

`"Authorization: Token {API KEY}"`

So you've missed the `Token` prefix before the token.
Change this line:

```
 con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
```

to

```
 con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token " + token);
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you a lot for your help!